# SQLAlchemy Bidirectional Association Proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, associations, relationship

I'm trying to create a simple many to many relationship with a mapping table containing metadata about the relationship it represents with association proxies on both ends using SQLAlchemy.  However, I can't seem to get it to work.  Here's the toy example I've been working with to try to figure it out:

```
Base = declarative_base()


def bar_creator(bar):

    _ = FooBar(bar=bar)
    return bar


class Foo(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'foo'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    bars = association_proxy('bar_associations', 'bar',
                             creator=bar_creator)


def foo_creator(foo):

    _ = FooBar(foo=foo)
    return foo


class Bar(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'bar'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    foos = association_proxy('foo_associations', 'foo',
                             creator=foo_creator)


class FooBar(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'fooBar'

    foo_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('foo.id'), primary_key=True)
    bar_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('bar.id'), primary_key=True)
    bazed = Column(Boolean)
    foo = relationship(Foo, backref='bar_associations')
    bar = relationship(Bar, backref='foo_associations')


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
make_session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = make_session()
foo0 = Foo(name='foo0')
session.add(foo0)
bar0 = Bar(name='bar0')
foo0.bars.append(bar0)
```

I added the `creator` functions so I could avoid writing an `__init__` that won't work for my actual use case (takes single argument), and included the creation of the `FooBar` in each because I read in some of the documentation that the item being appended needs to already have a linking table instance associated with it.  I'm sure I'm just missing something obvious (or maybe even trying to do something that just can't be done), but after much digging through the docs and Googling, I can't figure out why it doesn't work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you explain what exactly does not work? I don't see a reason why you need the `creator` functions for the association proxy.

Comment: It doesn't work with or without the creators, but the creators seem to make it get a little further along.  I get a key error for foo from sqlalchemy/orm/attributes.py", line 1140, in emit_backref_from_collection_append_event child_impl = child_state.manager[key].impl when appending bar0 to foo0.bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies in the `creator`: It should return the new instance of `FooBar` and not `bar` or `foo`:

```
def bar_creator(value):
    return FooBar(bar=value)
```

And analogous for `foo_creator`.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense.  It works now, thanks.  I knew it would be something stupid and obvious...

Comment: Lambdas can provide a nice way to avoid writing these extra creator functions, e.g.: `creator=lambda b: FooBar(bar=b)`